# Get index of a shallow tuple/list given an item in said tuple

Tags: python, sequences

What's a graceful way in Python to get an index of a shallow tuple given an itme in it?

#### Example

For words and spelling variants/aliases, get the word given any variant/alias:

```
words = (('word1')
         ('word2', 'variant2_1')
         ('word3', 'variant3_1', 'variant3_2')
         ...
         )

word = get_some_word()
if index_of_tuple_containing_word != None:
    word = words[index][0]
```

Notes:

1. variants are unique across words.
2. We don't want to unpack the structure into (word, variant) tuples.
3. The above can also apply to words or variants as keys in a dict, but I thought this structure is simpler.

Comment: We want to use the index to get the standard form of the word which is the first in the tuple in the exaple. Basically we are after a graceful way of representing words and aliases in an intuitive way then getting the standard form given any word/alias.

Answer (score 3):

For this example, I'd make a dict from word variants to their canonical forms:

```
words = {'word1': 'word1',
         'word2': 'word2', 'variant2_1': 'word2',
         'word3': 'word3', 'variant3_1': 'word3', 'variant3_2': 'word3',
         ...
}
word = words[word]
```

Lookup is constant-time, unlike the tuple of tuples, where lookup would require a brute-force search through about half the data structure. If you want all variants of a word, the value can be a list of variants.

If for some reason you really want to organize your data as a tuple of tuples, and you really want to compute an index into the outer tuple, you can write a function to do that easily enough:

```
def outer_index(item, nested_tuple):
    for i, inner_tuple in enumerate(nested_tuple):
        if item in inner_tuple:
            return i
    raise ValueError('{} is not in the nested tuple'.format(item))
```

It'll be slow, but if your data set isn't that big, it may be okay.

Comment: Please check my notes - this is a less friendly way for representing data if we can avoid it. Efficiency not an issue for this one as it's not a repeat op.

Comment: @BaselShishani: What makes it less friendly?

Comment: It fits more the structure of the data and easier to discern for the code reader, and for many aliases you double the length of the structure. Not terribly different, but would prefer compacted form if there is a simple idiom.

Comment: @BaselShishani: Is this data structure a literal somewhere in your code? If it is, then you probably don't need to worry about pathological behavior on large data sets. Make sure you change what you're doing if the literal gets huge, though. Also, if you need to, you can transform a tuple of tuples to a dict representation easily enough.

Comment: Many thanks. It's literal and it's not terribly huge. This whole thing is like a code recipe where people would copy it make few changes to the words or aliases, that's why I liked it to be in a more natural form.

Answer (score 0):

**OP:**

I also liked:

```
words = ( ('word1',('word1', 'alias11', 'alias111')),
          ('word2',('word2', 'alias22', 'alias222')),
          ('word3',('word3',)) )

someword = 'alias11'
lst = [cword for cword,aliases in words if someword in aliases]   
canonical = lst[0] if lst else None
```